# SQL Server and tables? Invalid object

Tags: php, sql-server, object

Firstly I'm a complete newbie when it comes to SQL Server. I have five SQL Server databases, in all of them except one I can easily do say...

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dt_Organizers
```

However one of the new databases require me to do this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbuser.dt_Organizers
```

Note that all the tables in all databases have "dbuser" "dbamy" "dbyon" "dbmio" "dbcana" prefixes respectively, this never caused a problem before. Now if I use the query without doing **dbuser**.dt_Organizers it brings up:

> Warning: mssql_query()
>   [function.mssql-query]: message:
>   Invalid object name 'dt_Organizers'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a look at

- [Understanding the Difference between
  Owners and Schemas in SQL Server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-the-difference-between-owners-and-schemas-in-sql-server)
- [SQL SERVER – Importance of Database
  Schemas in SQL Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/07/sql-server-importance-of-database-schemas-in-sql-server/)